# Conda: Frozen Solve vs Flexible Solve and skipping Flexible Solve

Tags: anaconda, package, conda

I have a few questions relating to how Conda handles package updates.

- What exactly is the difference between Frozen and Flexible Solves? I assume this interacts with the specified channels at some level but don't know how. Are there additional .condarc settings that influence the behavior of Frozen and Flexible Solves?
- Does Conda have an option to skip the "flexible solve" portion of an update/install? I'd like to get to the conflict report a bit faster.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67538952/570918 https://stackoverflow.com/q/72022029/570918